# Need To align checkboxes in foreach loop laravel

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

These checkboxes are in foreach loop and need to show these boxes horizontally or in a group

[image]

```
<div class="col-12">
                                            
    @foreach ($inactive_isos as $inactive_iso )
        {{-- <div class="wall text-center">   --}}
        <p> {{$inactive_iso->standard_name}}</p>
        <label class="brick tile-picker">
           <input type="checkbox">
           <i class="tile-checked"></i>
        </label>        
        {{-- </div> --}}
    @endforeach
                                            
</div>
```

Comment: update the piece of css code as well.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty simple.

You just need to add the `d-flex`-Class to your `div`, which surrounds your Loop-Items.

In this Case your surrounding `div` should look like this:

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex"><!-- Your Loop-Items --></div>
```

So your "final" Code could look like this: https://codepen.io/yeich/pen/OJWXNXq